# Can we use stripe and In-app purchase continuously

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to restrict user from accessing certain feature. For that I want to take two times fee from user . first fee by stripe  and Other by in-app purchase

But According to my investigation . Apple doesn't allow to use other api for a restricting and feature inside the mobile app.
Please Guide me.

Answer (score 4):

Apple rejects apps that use third parties payments systems for buying **virtual content**. It seems that it is your case. You have two variants:

**Use only In-app purchases.**
Pros:

- Application approving guaranteed

Cons:

- 30% of money goes to Apple

**Remove payments from application at all and move it to Web Site.**
Pros:

- You won't pay 30% to Apple

Cons:

- 50% chance that application would be approved to publication in App Store
- Bad user experience cause of redirecting users from app to web site.